# Error - WSO2 Deployment Synchronizer for Carbon 4.2.0-Based Products

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have 2 gateway Workers and 1 gateway Manager using a svn to syncronize deploys.

I'm using API manager 1.9.1,
java version "1.7.0_99",
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) and 
SVN versions 1.7.

I used [1] for configure, but the error below is shown at Workers:

```
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: '/opt/programas/wso2am/1.9.1/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api' is not a working copy
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:202)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:379)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:283)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:276)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.cleanup(SVNAdminArea.java:984)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.cleanup(SVNAdminArea.java:985)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminArea.cleanup(SVNAdminArea.java:985)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doCleanup(SVNWCClient.java:524)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doCleanup(SVNWCClient.java:482)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.cleanup(SVNClientImpl.java:892)
```

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer+for+Carbon+4.2.0-Based+Products

Comment: is this the only error in log? could you post the full error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the explanation.

1. You first start the manager node with proper configs. At this time the svn repo is empty. During the startup, manager node commits everything in repository/deployment/server folder to the repo.
2. After that, you start the worker nodes. What happens then is, it tries to checkout the artifacts from the svn repo. Now, when it tries to checkout the repository/deployment/server/synaps-configs/default/api folder, it finds the same folder in the file system. But, it is not under version control. Thats the reason for this exception.

What you have to do is, when you start the worker nodes for the first time, delete everything in the repository/deployment/server/ folder (not the folder itself) and start. Then, it will checkout everything from the svn repo which has been already committed by the management node.